# How to configure different Custom Error Pages for Web and Mobile Site?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config

Is there a way to configure different error pages for different portions of your web app?

Normally, for the web app I can configure a Custom error page in the web.config. e.g.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="standarderror.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="filenotfound.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```

Is there a way I can specify different pages for web and mobile site?

Comment: How do you separate different sites in one application?

Comment: The mobile site is in a subdirectory called mo. So xyz.com/mo/home.aspx would be the mobile page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create additional web.config file in mobile version subdirectory with only customerrors options.